# How to add IValueConverter to an existing Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a TextBox and I try to add an IValueConverter to the TextProperty-Binding in code behind.

```
        var bindingExpression = TextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        if (bindingExpression != null && bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Converter == null)
        {
            bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Converter = new MyConverter();
        }
```

In this step the following exception throws: **Binding cannot be changed after it has been used.**
How can I access the binding earlier to change the property?

Comment: have u checked the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create new `Binding` and apply it. You can get various properties from old `Binding` instance.

   or,
2. Use `Trigger` to apply conditional `Binding`, one with and another without `IValueConverter`.

Comment: How does the second solution works? Can you give an example? Creating a new Binding is not that elegant.